# WordPress post_status and meta_query

Tags: wp-query, tax-query, post-status

I created a custom post status and I would like to set auto-change (clients are filling two dates, *precomming* and *ongoing*).

How can I do auto-post-status change when it is after *precomming* or *ongoing* date?

I'm also trying to do my own post listing filter: When I'm filtering by custom field it's all good, but I can't filter by taxonomy called `job_listing_category`.

If guests select *art* category then show just *art* category posts:

```
$cat = get_terms('job_listing_category');
$cat_array = array();

foreach($cat as $cat){
  if($value == $cat->slug) {
    $cat_array[] = $cat->slug;
  }
}

$meta_query = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $cat_array
  )
);
```

But idk know why it's not working (even my `$cat_array` is not null, I get *art* cat there).

Comment: Hi, could you show us a little bit more of your code - especially the part where WP_Query is created?

Comment: https://www.pastiebin.com/5cc014d14a0ea